# Unable to load google map after capturing image with html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, html2canvas

I wanted to capture a google map image using html2canvas but the problem is when I capture the image I can not see the google map except the direction. Can somebody please help me with this.Below is the reference image as well I am attaching code with this.

```
function getScreenShot() {

      html2canvas(document.querySelector("#map")).then(canvas => {

      var img = canvas.toDataURL();
      window.open(img);
      height=height,
      width=width

  });
 }
```

[Before capturing image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SyWe.png)

[After capturing image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Evi6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use **staticmap** concept of google  map? Using staticmap you can easily create the image. You can see below function for the same.

```
  function getScreenShot() {
    //google static map url
    var staticM_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap";

    //Set the Google Map Center.
    staticM_URL += "?center=" + mapOptions.center.lat() + "," + mapOptions.center.lng();

    staticM_URL  += "&size=520x650";  //Set the Google Map Size. 

    staticM_URL  += "&zoom=" + mapOptions.zoom;  //Set the Google Map Zoom. 

    staticM_URL  += "&maptype=" + mapOptions.mapTypeId;//Set the Google Map Type.

    //Loop and add Markers.
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        staticM_URL  += "&markers=color:red|" + markers[i].lat + "," + markers[i].lng;
    }

   window.open(staticM_URL);
}
```

Some reference urls which will help you.
https://staticmapmaker.com/google/
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Take-Screenshot-Snapshot-of-Google-Maps-using-JavaScript.aspx

Comment: I have used google static map, but the thing is I have to use some flight path and icons as well as you can see on the map image so for that, I have used some javascript code. So, in this case, I wanted a screenshot of that particular image but as you can see I am not getting that as I want.

Comment: Can you please pass **useCORS: true** in the options, this fixed the issue for me?

Comment: Thanks. But I have also tried by using **useCORS** as well but if I use this I couldn’t get any response as I was opening in another window.

Comment: Same problem here, however I was trying to save the image in a pdf using jspdf. I was already using staticmap, but it only worked after passing useCORS: true on html2canvas call. Thanks @dipmala

Comment: Please put your whole code in jsfiddle or here so can get exact issue.